# regex to match space but escaped space

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string:
`rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --progress --delete -l -H /Users/ken/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages /Users/ken/Google\ Drive/__config-GD/ST3`

regex to match space but escaped space I have tried:

Firstly to match escaped space(or any).

`\\.`

http://regex101.com/r/uL0mP8
works.

Next, to match space exclude the escaped space(or any).

`(?!\\.)`

http://regex101.com/r/fK3sW9
does not work.

What is wrong with the code? javascript.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

`(?<!\\)` 
http://regex101.com/r/fZ5uP2 wokrs!

I should have used neggative **Negative Lookbehind**...

**EDIT2:**

```
var command0 = `rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --progress --delete -l -H /Users/ken/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages /Users/ken/Google\ Drive/__config-GD/ST3`;

var regex = new RegExp('(?<!\\)\s')
var commandA = command0.split(regex);
```

Error -
`Invalid regular expression: /(?<!\\)\s/: Invalid group`

oops, what is the workaround in JavaScript??

OK  lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript. I'm not sure how 
http://regex101.com
can output. perhaps PHP or others on serverside.

**EDIT3:**

This has been very tricky. See the full working code I post:

[shell command to child_process.spawn(command, [args], [options]) node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090792/shell-command-to-child-process-spawncommand-args-options-node-js)

Comment: `var str = "rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --progress --delete -l -H /Users/ken/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages /Users/ken/Google\ Drive/__config-GD/ST3"` 
`var n=str.split(" ");` will give you an array in n of all your parts...I'm not sure this is a perfect use of regex...breaking them into groups would be but i don't see you doing it.  Let me know.

Comment: Actually, I use the regex for the .split. I found an answer, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to match all spaces excluding what you're calling an "escaped space".

You should be able to achieve that with a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\)\s
```

Will match any space not preceded by `\`.

The second regex you were using `(?!\\.)\s` was using a negative lookahead, and searching for spaces not followed by `\(any character)`, which is why it didn't work.

Edit: Lookbehinds won't work in javascript, learned something new.

Comment: Yeah right, thanks! I will check your answer since it's the first. Chris

Comment: Thanks, although Sniffer was slightly before me :P

Comment: What about `foo \\ bar`?  Doesn't the negative lookbehind need to pass if there are an odd number of '\\'s but not an even number?  Often regex implementations require lookbehinds have fixed length, so I don't think this is doable in general.

Comment: Ah, good point - I was just about to ask for example as I didn't quite see what you were getting at. I'd +1 the comment if such a thing were possible.

Comment: actually, I've tried this regex in split of js. it generates an error. see my Edit, and please let me know your idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the second case you can use: `(?<!\\)`

**Edit:** I don't usually work with javascript so i don't know of any quick shortcut, so i think you can do this at two steps:

1. Perform a substitution *(replace)* using this regex: `\\\s`, replace with semicolon `;` like this: `var newCommand = command0.replace(/\\\s/g, ";");`
2. Then perform split using this regex: `\s` like this: `var result = newCommand.split(/\s/);`

Comment: @KenOKABE Welcome although i answered before Chris, check time :)

Comment: oh right, sorry. actually, I've tried this regex in split of js. it generates error. see my Edit, and please let me know your idea.

Comment: @KenOKABE So you want to split your command around non-escaped white spaces ?

Comment: Thanks @ Sniffer but actually, the code you presented does not work in JS context. The escape by back slash can be very tricky. See the full working code I post: Please check my edit of the question.